# How to detect that a certain string is not an email address but a twitter id?

Tags: regex

Is there a way to differentiate between an email address and a twitter id?
Both use the '@' character and the email regex will be contained by the twitter id regex.
What's the best way to approach this?
Should I require a whitespace before the '@' character in order to identify that it's a twitter id?

Comment: If **you** look at the string, can **you** detect the difference ?

Comment: @YochaiTimmer: Yes, of course. one has XXX@XXX.XX and the other is only @XXX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test that it's preceded by whitespace using `(?<=\s)` and then check for the valid characters of twitter IDs which are only `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

That gives you a resulting regex of: `(?<=\s|^)@[A-Za-z0-9_]+`

You could eventually add a check for a dot, comma or whitespace after it to check that it's properly formatted within a sentence and not some weird artifact:

```
(?<=\s|^)@[A-Za-z0-9_]+(?=[\s.,])
```

Note that the lookbehind and lookahead (`?<=` and `?=`) might not work in your language of choice, but I'll assume it does since you didn't specify.

Answer (score 4):

Not entirely sure which characters are allowed in twitter usernames, but basically like so:

```
/(?:^|\s)@[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+\b/
```

Comment: What's the group before the '@' character?

Comment: tests for beginning of string/line or space.

Answer (score 1):

A twitter id wouldn't pass an email regex check.

Regular email:

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$
```

twitter won't have the last characters:

```
^@[A-Za-z0-9_]+$
```

So check if it's a valid email, if not, check if it's a valid twitter ID

Farther reading:

[**How to Find or Validate an Email Address**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Comment: What if I write @TwitterId.co? Is '.' a valid twitter id character.

Comment: ok, I got it wrong the first time (missed understood the example) fixed.

Comment: And I forgot the $ exists. Now it makes more sense.

Comment: your email regex doesn't math tld like `museum` or ìnfo`

Comment: You can increase the length... {2,6} ... Or be creative... ^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)$

Answer (score 1):

Email addresses *never* start with an @, while twitter ids *always* do.

```
isTwitter = address[0] == '@'
```

Comment: Yes but I am extracting it from a large string so I'm using regex.

Comment: Then test this on the regex matches, or use a separate regex that requires whitespace in front of the @ sign for twitter IDs.